# Issues deserialising JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have some JSON data as shown here:

```
[
{"Article":
    {
        "ArticleID":0,
        "EngTitle":"Area of Interest",
        "EngExcerpt":"",
        "EngBody":"",
        "ArticleTag":
            {
                "TagAttribute1":"Selection",
                "TagAttribute2":"AreaOfInterest"
            }
    }
}
]
```

which to me looks fine but when it gets passed to a method on which the DeserializeObject is called, it results in an error.

Here is the code I have to deserialize the object:

```
List<ArticleJson> lstArticleJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ArticleJson>>(jsonData);
```

and here are the relevant models:

```
public class ArticleJson
{
    public Article Article { get; set; }
}

public partial class Article : BaseModel
{
public Article()
    {
        this.ArticleTag = new HashSet<ArticleTag>();
    }

    public string EngTitle { get; set; }
    public string EngExcerpt { get; set; }
    public string EngBody { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ArticleTag> ArticleTag { get; set; }
}

public partial class ArticleTag : BaseModel
{        
public string TagAttribute1 { get; set; }
    public string TagAttribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot see what I need to change to rectify the error that is getting thrown:-

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.ArticleTag]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path '[0].Article.ArticleTag.TagAttribute1', line 1, position 1538.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JSON with this edit:

```
"ArticleTag":
[
     {"TagAttribute1":"Selection",
     "TagAttribute2":"AreaOfInterest"}
]
```

It's because you have `IEnumerable<ArticleTag>` so even though you are sending only one object, you need to still specify it as a JSON array for the binder to be happy.

In the same way you can't do this in C#

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = new Foo();
```

The error you posted even tells you this:

> **To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])** or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add a couple of square brackets in the JSON.